Problems Loading FXML File in JavaFX with Maven: getResource Returns Null
I am developing a JavaFX application in IntelliJ IDEA using Maven, and I am having trouble loading an FXML file from code. When trying to load the file pago-view.fxml with FXMLLoader, I get null in the path from getResource, which prevents the file from loading correctly.
The file pago-view.fxml is located in src/main/resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/.
The method in the controller that tries to load pago-view.fxml is as follows:
 public class CompraController {
 @FXML
 protected void pagar() throws Exception {
     System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml"));
     AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml"));
 }}

When I run System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml"));, the result is null, indicating that the path is not found in the classpath. Project structure:

src/main/java: contains Java classes, including CompraController.
src/main/resources: contains FXML files, with the structure src/main/resources/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml.

My pom.xml file includes the Maven plugin for JavaFX:
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>co.edu.javeriana.proyectobdd.HelloApplication</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I have also tried adding the following configuration to ensure that the FXML files are copied correctly:
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

After running mvn clean package, the FXML file appears in target/classes/co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml, but FXMLLoader still cannot find it.
I have verified that src/main/resources is set as a resources folder in IntelliJ. I have run mvn javafx:run to ensure that the classpath is correctly set. I tried different paths in getResource, like /co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml and co/edu/javeriana/proyectobdd/pago-view.fxml.
How can I ensure that the FXML file is in the classpath and that FXMLLoader can find it correctly? Is there any additional configuration in Maven or IntelliJ that I should consider?

You seem to be doing everything correctly. We may need a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem (including the directory structure; your computer should have some kind of tree command for that). Though maybe someone else will be able to spot the problem.

I agree that this all looks correct, especially as the FXML file is in the expected location in the build. Maybe use some copy and paste from the file names in the terminal to the source code to make sure no weird invisible characters have got in there.

How did you create this project? Did you use the new project template offered by IntelliJ for JavaFX? Did the project run initially, then stop working after you made changes?

Another quick (and somewhat hacky) test you can do is System.out.println(getClass().getResource("CompraController.class"));. This will at least tell you where the JVM is looking for resources.
